# Lebesgue Stieltjes Integral for unbounded variation functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stochastic-processes

Why can not we define Lebesgue Stieltjes integral $\int_0^T f dg$ when $g$ is not a bounded variation function on $[0,T]$ ?

Comment: I just learnt from the book " Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations" by Philip E. Protter that if such an integral has to be defined for all continuous $f$ then $g$ is necessarily of bounded variation. The proof uses Banach Steinhauss Theorem.